# What is it called when a method has optional parameters?

Tags: c#

I have the following method in a class library:

```
    public virtual void PrintError(Exception e, string verboseMessage)
    {

    }
```

What I would like to do is to make verboseMessage optional (so you could, if you wanted to, call this with `PrintError(e);` for example. I tried to research this but I don't know what the term is for this - how is this done and what should I be looking into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called precisely [Optional arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

you may write:

```
public virtual void PrintError(Exception e, string verboseMessage = null)
{
   //... etc
}
```

where the default value for the optional argument `string verboseMessage` is going to be `null`, and then you can call the method like this:

```
MyClass.PrintError(someException);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
MyClass.PrintError(someException, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Optional parameter should be set inside the method declaration, like this:

```
public virtual void PrintError(Exception e, string verboseMessage = "defaul value")
{

}
```

So, whenever you omit the second parameter it will be send as `default value` (in my example).